# oracle client for windows 8 64bit

Tags: oracle, 64-bit, windows-8.1, oracleclient

I am developing an app in Delphi 2010 that needs to communicate with remote Oracle 11g database. Therefore I use the ADODB components. 
Everything is fine, as far as I am working on my desktop that has Windows 7 32-bit installed.

Problems started when I tried to deploy the app on Windows 7 64-bit with 64-bit Oracle Client installed. Luckily installing 32-bit client helped.

Unfortunately now I have to install it on my notebook with Windows 8 64-bit. None of the clients is working. I have already tried installing 64-bit client, 32-bit client, reinstalling both of them, installing then by OUI and manually, but without success.

Did anyone encounter this problem yet and managed to solve it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47959.pdf

Comment: Well, what specific error or behavior are you encountering?  "without success" is not a very useful description, is it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on .dll of connection of Delphi odbc. We has the same problems with C++Builder (Delphis Like). Odbc client .dll for oracle connections is developed only for 32 bits.

Unitl then we only can connect to server 64bits with client 32bits. 64 bits server and 64 bits clients dont work. Unless you find thirdpartner odbc component, who doesn't use a native odbc .dll. We tried to use SQLDirect, but doesn't work well in firsts versions.

Best Regards,
Diogo Maschio